# NSUserDefaults Permanent storage and Int conversion Swift Xcode

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults, data-storage

fairly new coder here and I've got a question about NSUserDefaults and permanent storage.

I'm toying around with making an app that has two tabs, one which times the player and one that has a record of the player's times and total time, it's these times that I would like to be recorded permanently.

I have an array in which I record these times called countTotal and I've set it as a global variable.

```
var countTotal: [Int] = [0,0,0]
```

And in one controllerInterface it updates the times in this array in accordance with the timer. The problem I have is saving this data permanently
I tried using NSUserDefaults, but at first I had problems with the data types, so I converted them all to int variables
I've used the code:

```
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(countTotal[0], forKey: "secondsSaved")
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(countTotal[1], forKey: "minutesSaved")
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(countTotal[2], forKey: "hoursSaved")

    var intSecondsSaved = Int(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(countTotal[0], forKey: "secondsSaved"))
    var intMinutesSaved = Int(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(countTotal[1], forKey: "minutesSaved"))
    var intHoursSaved = Int(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(countTotal[2], forKey: "hoursSaved"))

    countTotal[0] += intSecondsSaved
    countTotal[1] += intMinutesSaved
    countTotal[2] += intHoursSaved
```

But the data doesn't save when I reopen the app

What's wrong?

Also NSUserDefaults and stuff isn't coming up purple. Any suggested reading for this stuff? A lot of reading on this assumes knowledge I don't yet possess.

Comment: "But the data doesn't save when I reopen the app" How do you know?

Comment: "Coming up purple"????

Comment: Okay, well, so far it looks like you don't even know the difference between setting a value and getting a value. So you are nowhere near ready to write this code. You need to learn some basic programming concepts.

Answer (score 0):

To save permanently you need to use `synchronize` on NSUserDefaults.

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
```

Comment: So if I was to change:
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(countTotal[0], forKey: "secondsSaved")
To: 
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize().setInteger(countTotal[0], forKey: "secondsSaved")

Would that do the trick? Is there a guide on NSUserDefaults I can read?

Comment: No, that's not correct. The best reference is the documentation. Put NSUserDefaults into Google and it will prob be the first link. It's the best way to learn what different classes can do.

Comment: There are also loads of tutorials about NSUserDefaults. Try Ray Wenderlich site.

Comment: Okay, thank you, I looked at two pages before asking this question and they were pretty uninformative. I'm reading the apple documentation for the class now and I'll try the Ray Wenderlich site after, thank you

Comment: Sorry I can't help more atm. I'm on my iPad and it's nearly 4am. My brain is going to mush. Lol

Answer (score 0):

This line (and the following two) makes no sense at all:

```
var intSecondsSaved =
    Int(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        .setInteger(countTotal[0], forKey: "secondsSaved"))
```

That's nonsense. You have already *set* this value in user defaults. Now you are *setting* it again? More over, while you are setting it, you then take the "result", convert it to an Int, and set a variable to it?? But *setting* has no meaningful "result". Surely what you intend to be doing here is to *get* the value from NSUserDefaults, right?

Comment: Ah, I hadn't noticed that.

Comment: Ahh I see, I thought I was creating a variable with the assigned value, guess not.

Comment: Yes I would like to get the result.

Comment: I just want to store the three values of the array countTotal